# python opencv could not display video while using third party camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I have  written below code to read video from camera  to display and save .

when I run the below code with option 0 in VideoCapture(0), it works fine and display my webcam video, when I change it to 1 in VideoCapture(1) to get the video from third party camera, I get the error.

I am using the 3rd party camera, with their software it plays the video , I need to capture using my python code ..

with the  [apbase code](https://aptina.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DEVS/pages/3244088/ApBase+API+Development+Guide) qt example also it plays the video

I am not able to play using the below python code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
def nothing(x):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow('images')
switch = 'Recording'
cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'images',0,1,nothing)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def writeVideo(frmae):
    pass

switchstatus = 0

currentpos = 0
fourccs = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('sample.avi', fourccs, 20.0, (640,480))
created = 0
startrecord = 0



def RecordVideo(frame):
    global out
    global created;
    global startrecord
    print "In the Record video" ,created, startrecord
    if created == 0 and startrecord ==1:
        filename ='test.avi'
        filename=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+'.avi'
        print "filename", filename
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourccs, 20.0, (640,480))
        created = 1;
        out.write(frame)
    elif created == 1 and startrecord ==1:
        out.write(frame)


def positionChanged(s):
    global currentpos
    global created
    global startrecord

    print "position changed", s
    currentpos = s
    if s==1:
        startrecord = 1
        created = 0
    else:
        startrecord = 0
    if created==1:
        created =0
        out.release()




def switchchanged(s):
    global switchstatus;
    if switchstatus != s:
        switchstatus = s
        positionChanged(s)



while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
        RecordVideo(frame)
    cv2.imshow('images',frame)

    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch,'images')

    switchchanged(s)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Error

File "C:\Python32Bit\video.py, lime 89, in  cv2.imshow('images',frame)

eror :........\opencv\modules\hihggui\src\window.cpp:error:(-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Comment: On Linux systems `VideoCapture` by default uses `libv4l2` for video input devices. Install `v4l-utils` and do `v4l2-ctl --all`. See if it displays your camera.

Comment: I am trying on windows

Comment: For windows, it most probably uses `DShow`. With your display webcam, run `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`, if it works then it is using `DSHOW`.

Comment: 0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW   is working for my webcam, and 1+cv2.CAP_DSHOW is giving same error .  for testing purpose I cross checked, driver of that camera "aptina m031" are installed

Comment: OK, lets give this one more try. `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0+cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)`. Btw, did you install OpenCV from source or opencv_python bindings?

Comment: I tried with above option its same issue . I installed the opencv from https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/latest/download and copied cv2.pyd package under C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
```

it indeed solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by disabling the built-in webcam from the windows hardware settings menu. I did this on a friend's computer so I don't have access to it now, but check [this](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/windows-10/windows-10-how-to-completely-disable-your-webcam-camera/) out. I believe windows won't let openCV use any other video capture device but the 0th, so you have to make any camera you want to use the first in the hardware list.

Comment: Hi, I disabled default camera but still same issue , I noticed there is only camera under "Imaging Devices " my third party camera is coming under "Universal Serial Bus Controller " as "aptina Demo" , so is there any thing to do with this

Comment: have you installed the windows drivers for the camera?

Comment: Yes, then only it detected as aptina demo under "Universal Serial Bus Controller "

Comment: I'm not sure, I do know windows has this nice feature of not working on the first install of drivers, so you have to reinstall drivers. So you could try reinstalling them. Maybe do some of the classic Windows [troubleshooting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/web-camera-not-detected-imaging-devices-missing-in/4f1f6d17-dde6-4f4f-b8d7-7ed03ca608a1?page=3)

Answer (score 0):

You just change VideoCapture(0) to
VideoCapture (1) If you using external camera.
If we using computer camera then we are write (0)
So you can make that change

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30671342)